# Boost Ini-parser: preserve comments in ini-file on write

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to parse an Ini-file (using boost) and write some changed values back to the file.
A simple example for this is the following code (main.cpp):

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini("testini.ini", pt);

        int i = pt.get<int>("Section1.Value1");

        std::cout << i << std::endl;

        pt.put("Section1.Value1", 32);

        boost::property_tree::ini_parser::write_ini( "testini.ini", pt );
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

With this, I am accessing the following ini file (testini.ini):

```
[Section1]
; Test variable
Value1=1
```

This works quite well, however, the comment is not preserved and the newly written file looks like this

```
[Section1]
Value1=32
```

and what I wanted is

```
[Section1]
; Test variable
Value1=32
```

Now the question is, is there a way to preserve the comment in the file? It must not need to use the ini-parser!

Comment: I tried running the code referenced there and it does not work, it did still overwrite my comments :( So I am not sure it is duplicate. Did you check if it is working?

Comment: yes sorry, it probably couldn't help you. I am afraid you are unable to achieve what you want, unless you choose solution like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354838/writing-comments-to-ini-file-with-boostproperty-treeptree?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, I found this as well, but as far as I understand it, it cannot be used to preserve comments edited manually to the ini-file. However, this is often the case for me.

Comment: See also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341556/boost-property-tree-ini-parsing-gives-error-if-any-comment-is-appended-to-key-va

Comment: Looks like a different problem to me, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: It's impossible using boost because ini parser ignores comments, see [this](https://github.com/boostorg/property_tree/blob/develop/include/boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp#L99).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150630/discussion-between-andi-and-vasek).

Comment: @vasek it's not impossible using boost, but it is not a feature of Boost PropertyTree