# Boost info parser removes all the comments while reading/writing an INFO format file

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

Say, we have a file named a.conf

```
key3
{
  key4 "value4 with spaces" ;this is a key4
}
```

When I try to read an INFO formatted file having above content using the boost info parser in the following ways;

```
namespace p = boost::property_tree;
p::ptree pt;
std::ifstream input("a.conf");
pt::info_parser::read_info(input, pt); 
/*
....do some stuff (optional)
*/
```

and write back the content of `pt` in `a.conf`, the comment is removed.

```
std::ofstream output("a.conf");
write_info(output, pt);    
output.close();
```

The content of `a.conf` file after writing back;

```
key3
{
  key4 "value4 with spaces"
}
```

Is there a way to preserve these comments while reading/writing using boost info parser?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354838/writing-comments-to-ini-file-with-boostproperty-treeptree?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Just check the documentation http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.info_parser

> INFO round-trips except for the loss of comments and include directives.